# Regex or Java convert certain regions to lower string

Tags: java, regex, replace, case, case-sensitive

I have got a piece of regex `"([A-Z]|_)*"` to find upper case values of attributes in a xml document. I would like to turn all the findings into lower case. I know I can reference the found group with the `$` sign, but how can I pass the value of the `$`variable into a `toLowerCase()` function. I don't care if the solution involves java or if a simple text editor would do the trick, because it's a one time jobs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for this particular task, you should probably use an XML parser instead. Having said that, with regular expressions, you can use a [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to store the captured groups:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]|_)+"); 
String s = "test=\"UPPERCASE\" other=\"lowercase\" map=\"UPPER\"";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  String group = m.group(0);
  System.out.println(group.toLowerCase());  // will print "uppercase" and "upper"
}
```

Comment: you can use m.start() and m.end() to access the non matched parts as well. IE at the first match you need to copy from 0 to index m.start() as is, then add the converted lowercase, etc, etc.